# mule multiple various types of file upload into amazon s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, mule

```
<flow name="flow1">

        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\temp" moveToPattern="abc.txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <s3:create-object config-ref="Amazon_S3" bucketName="mulebucket"   key="img" doc:name="Amazon S3"/>
          <logger message="s3 upload done...:" level="INFO" />
    </flow>
```

**I want to upload multiple files into my s3 bucket.**
but above code upload only one file.
any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

The file inbound-endpoint will keep picking up files from the source directory and creating them in S3. I think the problem is you S3 object **key** is static, so it is overwriting the same file. You can chnage the **key** to be more dynamic by using the filename of the loaded file, something like so:

```
<s3:create-object config-ref="Amazon_S3" bucketName="mulebucket" key="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" doc:name="Amazon S3"/>
```